# JHBUILD install NetworkManager Ubuntu-13.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, pkg-config

I have a problem installing gnome in my ubuntu.

JHBUILD try install NetworkManager module but the build show the next error

```
configure: error: Package requirements (libnl-3.0 >= 3.2.7 libnl-route-3.0 
libnl-genl-3.0) were not met:

No package 'libnl-route-3.0' found
No package 'libnl-genl-3.0' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH enviroment variable if you installed software
in a non-standar prefix
```

I check the package and in ubuntu are named libnl-3-200, libnlroute-3-200 and libnl-genl-3-200.

I think that may be the problem, so you have to put the environment variable but I do not know how to add and I'll add.

I have Ubuntu 13.04 64 bits.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the development packages (the ones that ends in *-dev*).  In your particular case, [`libnl-route-3-dev`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/amd64/libnl-route-3-dev/filelist) and [`libnl-genl-3-dev`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/amd64/libnl-genl-3-dev/filelist).  As you can see in the links, those packages provide their respective pkg-config files (`.pc`).